# NSIS Uninstall Silent mode run in current cmd

Tags: nsis, silent, uninstallation

I write SetSilent in my nsis uninstaller, but when I call it from cmd, it opened in new cmd window. I need to run uninstall in my current cmd. Can you help me?

Comment: We need more information. NSIS is not a console application and will not open another console window by itself. Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer building NSIS as a console program for this purpose, however it is possible to allow a GUI program to write to an existing console window. The drawback to this method is that the input cursor doesn't move with the output, so the user will probably want to enter cls after install is complete, and you'll have to notify them of that fact. For extra credit, I've also added a DetectConsole function to automatically determine whether NSIS was called from the command line, but you'll need to include this header for GetProcessInfo:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Get_process_info

But in any event it's possible with something like the below. You can wrap your DetailPrint's in a macro that also does a StdOutPrint, and use nsExec::ExecToStack : https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsExec_plug-in and StdOutPrint the stack contents (though you'll probably want to use the NSIS long strings build to capture more verbose output).

If you want to use the /S parameter to open a new command window if necessary even if not called from the command line (a noisy silence), then uncomment the 4 lines with ";${OrIf} ${Silent}" and ";SetSilent silent"

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include GetProcessInfo.nsh
Var /GLOBAL StdOutHandle
Var /GLOBAL CommandLine

Function ${UN}AttachConsole  # Reuse or create a command prompt window if command line install
    Push $0
    Push $1
    StrCpy $StdOutHandle ""
    ${If} $CommandLine == "yes"
    ;${OrIf} ${Silent}
        System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0'
        System::Call 'kernel32::AttachConsole(i -1)i.r1'
        ${If} $0 = 0
        ${OrIf} $1 = 0
            System::Call 'kernel32::AllocConsole()'
            System::Call 'kernel32::GetStdHandle(i -11)i.r0'
            StrCpy $StdOutHandle $0
            FileWrite $StdOutHandle "\r\n"
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
FunctionEnd

!macro StdOutPrint OutputText
    ${If} $CommandLine == "yes"
    ;${OrIf} ${Silent}
        FileWrite $StdOutHandle `${OutputText} \r\n`
    ${EndIf}
!macroend
!define StdOutPrint '!insertmacro StdOutPrint'

Function ${UN}DetectConsole  # Check if run from a command line (including some known cmd.exe replacements)
    Push $0
    Push $1
    Push $2
    Push $3
    Push $4
    Push $5
    ${GetProcessInfo} 0 $0 $1 $2 $3 $4  # $0=pid $1=parent_pid $2=priority $3=name $4=fullname
    ${GetProcessInfo} $1 $0 $1 $2 $3 $5
    ${If}   $3 == "wsmprovhost.exe"     # Remote PowerShell [stdout OK, but no stdin]
    ${OrIf} $3 == "powershell.exe"      # Local PowerShell
    ${OrIf} $3 == "cmd.exe"             # Command Prompt
    ${OrIf} $3 == "tcc.exe"             # Take Command
    ${OrIf} $3 == "4nt.exe"             # 4NT
    ${OrIf} $3 == "console2.exe"        # Console2
    ${OrIf} $3 == "conemu.exe"          # ConEmu
    ${OrIf} $3 == "conemu64.exe"        # ConEmu x64
    ${OrIf} $3 == "clink_x86.exe"       # clink
    ${OrIf} $3 == "clink_x64.exe"       # clink x64
    ${OrIf} $3 == "FireCMD.exe"         # FireCMD
    ${OrIf} $3 == "far.exe"             # Far Manager
    ${OrIf} $3 == "mintty.exe"          # Cygwin/Git
    ${OrIf} $3 == "Cmder.exe"           # Cmder
    ${OrIf} $3 == "PowerCmd.exe"        # PowerCmd
        ;SetSilent silent
        StrCpy $CommandLine "yes"
    ${EndIf}
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
    Call DetectConsole
    ${If} $CommandLine == "yes"
    ;${OrIf} ${Silent}
        Call AttachConsole
        ${StdOutPrint} "Hello, world!"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```